# ¿Función nativa en PHP para extraer último / primer elemento de un array asociativo?

Tags: php

Viendo que las funciones ***array_pop*** y ***array_shift***, extraen el elemento, pero devuelve sólo su valor, perdiéndose la clave en el caso de arrays asociativos, ¿cuales serían, si la hay, las funciones nativas para obtener el elemento (compuesto por su clave y su valor), reduciendo a su vez en uno el tamaño del array de origen?

Ahora uso las siguientes funciones propias para obtener este comportamiento:

```
function array_pop_assoc(array &$arr)
{
    $slice = array_slice($arr, (count($arr) - 1));
    array_pop($arr);


    return $slice;
}

function array_shift_assoc(array &$arr)
{

    $slice = array_slice($arr, 0, 1);
    array_shift($arr);


    return $slice;
}
```

Comment: @Marcos Añadidas funciones

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) para **obtener y remover** del arreglo el primer y ultimo elemento.

### Ejemplo:

```
function array_pop_assoc(array &$arr)
{
    return array_splice($arr, -1);
}

function array_shift_assoc(array &$arr)
{
    return array_splice($arr, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Creo que es una buena alternativa a mi código. 
Esta función lo la conocía. Saludos.

Comment: es bueno saberlo  :), como sólo necesitas la última posición te sobra con indicar solo 2 parámetros: el array y -1. 

Saludos y feliz año nuevo.

Comment: Si, ya te he votado, espero un poco a ver si alguien aporta otras soluciones antes de aceptarla. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza las funciones para mover el puntero dentro del arreglo y asi obtener el valor como la key antes de hacer array_shift o array_pop

```
function array_pop_assoc(array &$arr)
{
    end($arr);
    $temp = [key($arr) => current($arr)];
    array_pop($arr);
    return $temp;
}

function array_shift_assoc(array &$arr)
{
    reset($arr);
    $temp = [key($arr) => current($arr)];
    array_shift($arr);
    return $temp;
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Es una posible alternativa, pero a primera vista no me parece una mejora de las funciones propuestas. Saludos.